# LDA process failing in PySpark due to increased max iteration parameter

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, lda

I'm running LDA on ~300K documents using 4 `r3.4xlarge` instances on Amazon EMR. With `k=800` topics, a mini-batch `fraction = 0.2` and `maxIter=20` (or 10), the job finishes, but if I increase maxIter to 30, for example, the job fails. I'm having a difficult time reasoning about why increasing maximum iterations would cause a job to fail. I tried playing around with checkpointing, but I'm not sure really how that would help (and the Spark code isn't exactly self-documenting in this regard). Anyone run into similar issues?

Comment: I've run into a similar issue sometime before, and I was not able to get a correct reliable answer on this too..

Answer (score 0):

A checklist:

- Did you enabled checkpointing (`setCheckpointInterval`)?

  - If yes, did you set checkpoint directory?

    - If no set checkpoint directory:

      ```
      sc.setCheckpointDir(...)
      ```
    - If yes please confirm that checkpoints are actually written and there is enough space on the device.
  - If no enable checkpointing.

Comment: If I'm running on EMR should I specify an S3 path for the directory or local like /home/...?

Comment: Docs: _Set the directory under which RDDs are going to be checkpointed. The directory must be a HDFS path if running on a cluster_ but I am not sure if S3 is a good choice for that.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to have fixed the problem.